# How to make async functions (like OpenStreamForWriteAsync) synchronous?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, task-parallel-library

I am working on an windows phone 8 app. I have to save video into camera roll folder.

To get a file stream for camera roll folder, I am using following [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147.aspx):

```
[CLSCompliantAttribute(false)]
public static Task<Stream> OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
    this IStorageFile windowsRuntimeFile
)
```

For example:

```
Stream videoStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
```

where file is [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147.aspx).

I want to remove this await and make function synchronous because of requirements.

EDIT:
PS: I am executing this function on different thread and I want that thread to be synchronous. I want to write on that file stream after it is created.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are your requirements?

Comment: To go a step further: The correct answer is "change your requirements". Windows Phone 8 apps should be asynchronous, with a responsive UI.

Comment: I don't understand, why would you want “thread to be synchronous”? You can certainly write on the returned stream after it is created if you use `await`, you don't need to wait for the result synchronously for that.

Comment: @svick According to my understanding after reading msdn documents, await should make the call synchronous i,e if I call the function with await then i should get the result, but still sometimes I get null refrence exception while writing to stream. My whole team is facing issue with async-await api's.

Comment: @user1187575 If you get an exception, then you should fix that exception (maybe ask another question about that). It certainly shouldn't be a reason to make your code synchronous. And `await` doesn't make your code synchronous, it makes your code *look* almost as synchronous code (i.e. no callbacks).

Comment: were you able to successfully save video to the media library? Every approach I took, I got slammed with the unauthorized access exception.

Comment: If your understanding is that "await makes it synchronous" then your understanding is 100% incorrect.  Await means "the current thread can go do something else until this task completes; after this task completes, resume execution of this method at this point".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply access `Result`:

```
Stream videoStream = file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync().Result;
```

This will block until the task finished its execution.
Please note that this can result in a deadlock of your program, if that code is executed on the UI thread.
Please refer to [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for further information.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Sure. But isn't that exactly what he is requesting? And you don't know whether it is executed on the UI thread or not. Your downvote is not justified.

Comment: To just say "use `Result`" for a general question about making async methods synchronous - without pointing out the extremely common deadlock problem - is not a good answer. Hence my downvote. If you edit to include a mention of the deadlock problem, I'll remove it. Bonus points if you include alternative approaches that don't deadlock and point out the pitfalls of each.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Looks like your downvote is justified after all. When you said "deadlock" I thought you meant "block". But you do mean deadlock. I don't have the necessary experience with await/async to explain why the deadlock can happen and how to avoid it. I suggest you post an answer yourself. I would appreciate that.

Comment: I have [a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that describes why the deadlock happens. The best answer ("change your requirements") I put on a comment to the question since it's not really an *answer*... Unfortunately, there is no one solution that will always work; each one has its own drawbacks.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks for the link. I added it to the answer - and will read it now myself ;-)